# Javascript: Find and replace tag

Tags: javascript, replace, onclick, tags

I'm trying to find `<body onload="function();">` and replace it with `<body>` on `onClick` event.

Any suggestions how this could be done?

Thank you.

**UPD.**
Sorry for an unclear question. **Crozin** answered my question, I was just trying to remove `onload` attribute.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me.  It sounds like you're trying to remove body's onload listener dynamically when another element is clicked.  But that should be unnecessary because onload isn't going to fire again anyway.

Comment: Can you put a little more context around this? For example: are you doing this client side, processing a page in another language, loading a page via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to search and replace String or DOM Element? If string then use this:

```
var str = "....<body onliad=\"function();\">....";
var replaced = str.replace("<body onload=\"function();\">", "<body>");
```

If you want to delete `onload` attribute from DOM element use this:

```
document.body.removeAttribute("onload");
```